# Port forwarding with VPN

Tags: vpn, ports, port-forwarding

EDIT: My VPN has port forwarded a 5-digit tcp/udp port for me.
**What kind** of attacks am I opening the computer to with VPN port forwarding?

Answer (score 2):

Any open port is susceptible to probes/attacks, it all depends on what service/application is running on it and how vulnerable is that service/application itself.

For VPN:

- If using application, you need to find out how vulnerable is your VPN application.
- What cipher suits are used.
- Implement strong authentication measures.
- Keep log of connections.

Comment: AES-256, SHA1, RSA-2048, udp-connection, no dns leaks